# How to make multiple light array objects follow curve path with rotation as well?

Tags: lighting, instances

I was trying to array large amount of lamp posts across my scene with the lamp post being "face instancing" on a rectangle with array and curve modifiers.

I want two light object located at each lamp, so I parent them towards the rectangle, and now I face the issue of light objects are not rotating according to the reference curve.

Attached File:

[image]

[image: Light not rotating according to ref curve.]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). I'm unable to reproduce the issue. If you share the file I'll be sure to look into it :).

Comment: hello Jachym, I meet the same problem, could you please share your file?

Comment: I had updated post with attached blender file, please take a look thanks!